# WCF Test client only loading services in same project

Tags: wcf

I restructured a WCF project to separate the service.cs and contracts to separate projects. In the main  WCF project I place only a service.svc file that references (dll, not service reference) the service class. I also updated app.config to reflect the change.

Once I do this, the wcf test client no longer loads the service. It gives no errors. I can publish to my local IIS and it still works just fine.

Do I need to add something to the wcftestclient.exe command line options?

Answer (score 0):

Is the dll of the project that has the contracts in there also? Make sure to copy **everything** from the bin/debug (or bin/release) into IIS virtual directory.

Comment: I am using f5 debug, not IIS. All the referenced project dlls are generated to the main project's bin folder.